# Remove the last comma in an inline list of tags?

Tags: templating, tags, conditional, forloop

In a list of tags I'd like to remove the last comma. So is there something that works like the Ee backspace parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An alternative, if you are getting the tags from the [Tag Field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/tags-fields) type, is the [Join](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) filter:

```
{% if post.tags | length %}
    Tags: {{ post.tags | join(', ') }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Very clever and simple, ideal for tags :-)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

There's a couple of [special variables](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) available while for looping through an array. In your case I'd make use of [`loop.last`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable).

```
{{ tag }}{{ not loop.last ? ', ' }}
```

This is the expression using the [ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) to keep the syntax short.

Comment: @noregt no love for the CSS solution?

Comment: Not really, if it's a list I'd also rather not have the separator in the html. (comma, backslash or similar)

Comment: That's the exact reason to use CSS over HTML, @noregt! You'd only apply the class to those inline lists you wanna STYLE like this.

Comment: I meant the LAST parsed separator, but I get your point if you're working with official lists. I was working with a simple paragraph line and comma's. But I admit that's not very good html.

Answer (score 5):

If you you have a given string and can't influence how it is generated, use the [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter to crop that last comma:

```
{% set tags = 'Alpirsbacher Klosterbräu, Rothaus Tannenzäpfle, Neumarkter Lammsbräu, ' %}

{# Remove the last two chars ", " from the string #}
{{ tags|slice(0, -2) }}
```

Comment: Aha that's even better, so slice is the EE backspace alternative :-)

Comment: No, it's the worst way to do it in my opinion, @noregt!

Comment: Haha I understand your annoyance, but essentially I wanted to know the alternative for the EE backspace parameter. You changed the title, but that was what I meant to ask.

Comment: Yep, I think the new title fits this Q/A better. You asked for a way to make your tag list and that EE thing was just a side note for me (yes, there are people using Craft NOT coming from EE :D). Cheers, @noregt.

Comment: Oh, and it's your question. Don't feel being pushed to accept the CSS solution! (but do it!!!)

Answer (score 3):

What about using CSS for that?

```css
.u-inlineList {
  display: inline;
}

.u-inlineList-item {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.u-inlineList-item:after {
  content: ", ";
}

.u-inlineList-item:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: That is an option, but I would prefer if that can be done through craft. Or can't it?